# string concatenation c++ I am getting a error C2679

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

When I try to output "result" to the console I get a error with the insertion operator. Help please!!

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>                 
int main()
{
    string result;
    string s1 = ("hello ");
    string s2 = ("world");
    result = s1 + s2;

    cout << result;

        return 0;
}
```

Error:

1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

2 IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
operand types are: std::ostream << std::string

Thank You

Comment: Show your includes and post the full error message.

Comment: Include headers for the things you use.

Comment: I have no problems running that code. http://ideone.com/Q3Gsjk

Comment: @Cyber you're not running THAT code, you have added `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`, right? Them it's different code.

Comment: @Dawid it would appear so. Before the OP updated with their includes, I had assumed they knew to include <string>, guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add `#include <string>` to the top of the file. Also add `using namespace std;` before `main()`.

Comment: Thank you I know a few people said that I am new to c++ and coding in general so thank you very much